# Help identify a collection of short stories

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The book cover was a tiny dog in the palm of a human hand. There were many stories and the ones I remember are as follows:

- A girl whose parents ignore her finds a town of people who are all shrunk to the size of dolls and a woman offers her the chance to join them
- Boy realizes that he can't grow older than age 5 because his parents gave him an injection and he meets an older kid who explains everything to him

Please help me, It's driving me crazy

Comment: About how old is the book?

Comment: I can't find anything that exactly matchs your description, but the story about the boy who cannot age sounds somewhat like Ray Bradbury's "Hail and Farewell".

Answer (score 5):

[image: Unexpected - Book Cover - tiny dog in hand]

Is this, *[Unexpected: 11 Mysterious Stories](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6396827-unexpected-11-mysterious-stories)*, edited by Laura E. Williams, the book? I personally like the one with the dolls. I forgot what some stories were but i remember a few names: "Loser", "Infinity Jinx", and "Who Murdered Henry Horse".

> An Introduction by the editor and 11 stories. An eerie house filled with forgotten treasures... A young detective from the future... A miniature village that feels like home... A mom abducted by trolls...
>
> These are just a few of the eleven mysterious encounters conjured up by some of today's most popular and acclaimed authors.

List of stories courtesy of [Maury County Public Library's page](https://catalog.maurycountylibrary.org/Mobile/Search/Details/1.95044):

> - Loser / Peter Lerangis
> - Little time / Gail Carson Levine
> - Max, the hand, and me / Heidi E.Y. Stemple and Jane Yolen
> - Baby from outer space / Norma Fox Mazer
> - Who broke Harry's head? / Graham Salisbury
> - The troddler / Bruce Coville
> - Infinity Jinx / Margaret Peterson Haddix
> - Marked for death / Will Weaver
> - The telltale croak / Laura E. Williams
> - Dear, dear Kitty / Marion Dane Bauer
> - Sleuth 2500 / Dian Curtis Regan.

Comment: ISFDB entry pending

Answer (score 2):

The second story could be Harlan Ellison's "[Jeffty is Five](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeffty_Is_Five)" (Originally published in the 1977 *Magazine of Fantasy & Science Fiction* and [repeatedly collected](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?49824)).

It involves a boy who remains five years old while his friend ages normally. His aging (or lack of it) wasn't the result of an injection.

You can read the story online [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=BB0rAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT25&lpg=PT25&dq=%22What+I+mean+by+five+years+old+is+not+that+Jeffty+was+retarded%22&source=bl&ots=UQcjBqFnWX&sig=Q3VGVmkbTeByCAPzbi55aw2Rw4w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjhr8Oq55rSAhXpB8AKHUO5CRMQ6AEIIDAB#v=onepage&q=%22What%20I%20mean%20by%20five%20years%20old%20is%20not%20that%20Jeffty%20was%20retarded%22&f=false)